# Time based notifications service

Tags: node.js, events, triggers, notifications, webhooks

I am dealing with subscriptions where a user is subscribed to a plan and it has an **expiration**.

So basically each user store has an `expiration` field.

I want to be able to get notified when a user plan is expired as soon as it is actually expired.

Right now, I have a job that runs on all users once a day and check if anyone has expired but ideally I would like to get a server postback or some sort of event whenever a user is expired without running this each day.

Can you think of any third party service / database / other tool that deals with these sort of things ?

A lot of services, Stripe for example, notify you with a webhook whenever a user's subscription is renewed / expired. Are they just running a job repeatedly like I am ?

Hope I made myself clear enough, would appreciate help in how to focus my search in Google as well.

My current stack is Mongodb, Node.js, AWS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not know for sure, how Stripe handles it.

There are two solutions coming to my mind. Let's start with the simple one:

#### Cronjob

As you mentioned, you already have a *Cronjob* solution, but you can instead make it run each hour, or each 10 minutes. Just ensure you optimize your query to the maximum, so that it is not super-heavy to run.

It is attractive, easy to implement, very few edge cases, but as you might have though can be a performance drag once you reach millions of clients.

#### Timers

Implementation varries, and you need to worry about the edge cases, but the concept:

1. On day start* (00:00) query for all clients who are set to expire today, save them into array (in-memory). Sort the array by time (preferably descending).
2. Create timer to execute on last array's element time.
3. Function: If **Client X** expires now, query database to ensure subscription was not extended. Notify if it wasn't.
4. Remove **Client X** from the tracked array. Repeat step **2**.

On day start* - Also run it on script launch.

Comment: Are there any "timers as a service"  services out there that you know of ? even though it's  not too hard to develop myself, I am sure this is a common case enough that services have been built around it. Or not ? :)

Comment: @Michael sure there are services for everything. I do not know any in particular, also it is against the SO policy to ask for specific software / supplier.